# How to print only first two digits of the floating value (round down) in QWeb

Tags: xml, qwebview, qweb

Hi I need to print the value 10.50785 as 10.50 instead of 10.51.

I tried like this `<t t-esc="'{0:,.2f}'.format(float(10.50785))"/>`, but it's returning the value as 10.51.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [`_wrapped_report_class`](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-to-define-a-custom-methods-functions-to-be-used-in-a-qweb-report-how-to-define-and-use-a-report-parser-92244), define a function like

```py
_floor(self, value):
    return math.floor(value * 100) / 100 # Since you'd like to get 2 digits it's 100
```

or if you may want to use the same thing with a different number of digits:

```py
_floor(self, value, n):
    return math.floor(value * math.pow(10, n)) / math.pow(10, n)
```

Don't forget to import the math lib on the top of the class.

```
import math
```

Then in your qweb `t-esc`:

```xml
<t t-esc="'{0:,.2f}'.format(floor(10.50785))"/>
```

This is just an example of calling defined function in the wrapped report class from the qweb, but I hope you got the idea.